# csharp-mode.el: syntax highlighting and nothing else

Tags: emacs

I am loooking for an emacs mode which just does C# syntax highlighting and nothing else. *The csharp-mode.el* which I found on the net (http://code.google.com/p/csharpmode/) indents, inserts closing braces and ignores TABs. I want emacs to just write down what I type.

The emacs menu of this mode doesn't have an item to disable this behaviour (as the C mode has). In the manual of the csharp mode I didn't find any hint. I don't know Lisp, so I cannot dive into the code of csharp-mode.el to adapt it to my needs.

Any help?

Comment: Either get the maintainer to fiddle in the feature or hack it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hook to disable the local key bindings installed by `csharp-mode`:

```
(add-hook 'csharp-mode-hook (lambda () (use-local-map nil)))
```

Comment: I haven't the faintest idea what that means, but I included this line in my startup file and it apparently does exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!